# How to make a polymorphic assoication with Tags, Users and Articles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm making a Tag system where I want users to be able to create tags that can have descriptions. The tags belong to users and will eitherbe created alone or with an article. I want to be able to do things like `Tag.users` or `Tag.articles` to see all the articles or users that belong to a tag. Here is what I have so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible # Devise
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles
  has_many :tags

  # Table - using Devise
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings
  belongs_to :article

   # Table - user_id, article_id, name, description
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :content, :published_on
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  belongs_to :user

  # Table - user_id, name, content, published_on
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user

 # Table - user_id, tag_id, article_id
end
```

Is this the correct way to do what I want?

What attributes must be accessible and what are the associations?

Comment: is a user creating a tag? prob want a belongs_to :user on the tag class

Comment: @timpone Yeah, users are the only ones who create the tags.